# Converting to and from numpy's np.random.RandomState and Python's random.Random?

Tags: python, numpy, random, mersenne-twister, numpy-random

I would like to be able to convert back and forth between Python's standard Random and numpy's np.random.RandomState. Both of these use the Mersenne Twister algorithm, so it should be possible (unless they are using different versions of this algorithm).

I started looking into the getstate/setstate and get_state/set_state methods of these objects. But I'm not sure how to convert the details of them.

```
import numpy as np
import random

rng1 = np.random.RandomState(seed=0)
rng2 = random.Random(seed=0)

state1 = rng1.get_state()
state2 = rng2.getstate()
```

Inspecting each state I see:

```
>>> print(state1) 
('MT19937', array([0, 1, 1812433255, ..., 1796872496], dtype=uint32), 624, 0, 0.0)
>>> print(state2) 
(3, (2147483648, 766982754, ..., 1057334138, 2902720905, 624), None)
```

The first state is a tuple of size 5 with the `len(state1[1]) = 624`.

The second state is a tuple of size 3 with `len(state2[1]) = 625`. It seems like the last item in the state2 is actually the 624 in state1, which means the arrays are actually the same size. So far so good. These seem reasonably compatible.

Unfortunately the internal numbers don't have an obvious correspondence, so a seed of 0 results in different states, which makes sense because `rng1.rand() = .548` and `rng2.random() = .844`. So, the algorithm seems slightly different.

However, I don't need them to correspond perfectly. **I just need to be able to set the state of one rng from the other deterministicly without influencing the state of the first.**

Ideally, once I used the state of the first to set the state of the second, without calling any random methods, and then used the second to set the state of the first, the first state would remain unchanged, but this is not a requirement.

Currently I have a hacked together method that just swaps the 624-length list I can extract from both rngs. However, I'm not sure if there are any problems with this approach. Can anyone more knowledgeable on this subject shed some light?

Here is my approach, but I'm not sure that works correctly.

```
np_rng = np.random.RandomState(seed=0)
py_rng = random.Random(0)

# Convert python to numpy random state (incomplete)
py_state = py_rng.getstate()
np_rng = np.random.RandomState(seed=0)
np_state = np_rng.get_state()
new_np_state = (
    np_state[0],
    np.array(py_state[1][0:-1], dtype=np.uint32),
    np_state[2], np_state[3], np_state[4])
np_rng.set_state(new_np_state)

# Convert numpy to python random state (incomplete)
np_state = np_rng.get_state()
py_rng = random.Random(0)
py_state = py_rng.getstate()
new_py_state = (
    py_state[0], tuple(np_state[1].tolist() + [len(np_state[1])]),
    py_state[1]
)
py_rng.setstate(new_py_state)
```

---

EDIT:

Doing some investigation I checked what happens to the state over 10 calls to a random function.

```
np_rng = np.random.RandomState(seed=0)
py_rng = random.Random(0)

for i in range(10):
    np_rng.rand()
    npstate = np_rng.get_state()
    print([npstate[0], npstate[1][[0, 1, 2, -2, -1]], npstate[2], npstate[3], npstate[4]])

for i in range(10):
    py_rng.random()
    pystate = py_rng.getstate()
    print([pystate[0], pystate[1][0:3] + pystate[1][-2:], pystate[2]])


['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 2, 0, 0.0]
['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 4, 0, 0.0]
['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 6, 0, 0.0]
['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 8, 0, 0.0]
['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 10, 0, 0.0]
['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 12, 0, 0.0]
['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 14, 0, 0.0]
['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 16, 0, 0.0]
['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 18, 0, 0.0]
['MT19937', array([2443250962, 1093594115, 1878467924, 2648828502, 1678096082], dtype=uint32), 20, 0, 0.0]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 2), None]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 4), None]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 6), None]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 8), None]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 10), None]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 12), None]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 14), None]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 16), None]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 18), None]
[3, (1372342863, 3221959423, 4180954279, 418789356, 20), None]
```

I expect that the first item in each tuple is just the version of the algorithm they are using.

Its interesting to see that the 624 integers do not seem to change. Is this always the case?

However, I'm still unsure what the final None means in the Python version and the final 2 number are in the numpy version.

Comment: Can you explain the underlying reason for this question?

Comment: I have an algorithm pipeline that I want to seed. Some functions use python's rng and other's use numpy's rng. Occasionally one is used in the inner loop of the other. I have to pass rng's in to each function that uses it, so I want a way that I can seamlessly convert back and forth between them without doing something messy like seeding one with the random value of the other.

Comment: I need to ensure that the output is deterministic on the input. The result of the function I'm working with is a sample of data, and that sample has an associated hash. If the hash is different, then a very time-consuming indexing algorithm will run, otherwise a cached version is used. Mark Dickinson's answer gives me exactly what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The form of the NumPy `RandomState` state is [documented](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.get_state.html#numpy.random.RandomState.get_state):

> Returns:   out : tuple(str, ndarray of 624 uints, int, int, float)
>
> The returned tuple has the following items:
>
> 1. the string ‘MT19937’.
> 2. a 1-D array of 624 unsigned integer keys.
> 3. an integer pos.
> 4. an integer has_gauss.
> 5. a float cached_gaussian.

The last two entries there refer to the state of the generator for standard normal deviates: [NumPy uses](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c90d7c94fd2077d0beca48fa89a423da2b0bb663/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L598-L624) the [Box–Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform), which generates these deviates in pairs. So the first call to the gaussian generator produces two values, returns the first, and then stores the second away for later use. The second call then retrieves that second value. Thus we have extra state here that it's necessary to store and retrieve.

The form of the Python `Random` state is not documented, but is easy to extract from the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/random.py#L127-L129). As of CPython 3.6.1, it looks like this:

```
def getstate(self):
    """Return internal state; can be passed to setstate() later."""
    return self.VERSION, super().getstate(), self.gauss_next
```

Again, Python generates normal deviates in pairs, and `self.gauss_next` is `None` if there's no extra normal deviate stored, and the value of the stored deviate if there's one available.

To find out what `super().getstate()` returns, you need to dive into the [C source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Modules/_randommodule.c#L318-L343): it's a tuple of length 625, containing the 624 words that form the Mersenne Twister state, together with the current position in that collection of words. So the last entry in that tuple corresponds to the value `pos` at index 2 of the NumPy state.

Here's an example of converting from Python state to NumPy state, ignoring the details of the gaussian information:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, May 23 2017, 18:09:41) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import random
>>> np_rng = np.random.RandomState(seed=0)
>>> py_rng = random.Random(0)
>>> version, (*mt_state, pos), gauss_next = py_rng.getstate() 
>>> np_rng.set_state(('MT19937', mt_state, pos))
```

After setting the NumPy `RandomState` state from the Python `Random` state, we see that floats generated from the two RNGs coincide:

```
>>> py_rng.random(), np_rng.uniform()
(0.8444218515250481, 0.8444218515250481)
>>> py_rng.random(), np_rng.uniform()
(0.7579544029403025, 0.7579544029403025)
>>> py_rng.random(), np_rng.uniform()
(0.420571580830845, 0.420571580830845)
```

And here's the reverse transformation:

```
>>> _, words, pos, _, _ = np_rng.get_state()
>>> py_rng.setstate((3, tuple(map(int, words)) + (pos,), None))
```

And as before, we can check that the output of the two generators matches:

```
>>> py_rng.random(), np_rng.uniform()
(0.5488135039273248, 0.5488135039273248)
>>> py_rng.random(), np_rng.uniform()
(0.7151893663724195, 0.7151893663724195)
>>> py_rng.random(), np_rng.uniform()
(0.6027633760716439, 0.6027633760716439)
>>> all(py_rng.random() == np_rng.uniform() for _ in range(1000000))
True
```

Python and NumPy use different algorithms to generate normal deviates (although both algorithms used generate those deviates in pairs), so even if we transfer the gaussian-related state, we can't expect generated normal deviates to match. But if all you want to do is somehow preserve the Python state information in the NumPy state object (and vice versa), so that converting from one state to the other and back again doesn't lose information, that's easy enough to do: if `has_gauss` is zero in the NumPy state, use `None` for the last entry of the Python state, and if `has_gauss` is non-zero, use the value of `cached_gaussian` from the NumPy state in the last entry of the Python state. Here's a pair of functions implementing those conversions:

```
PY_VERSION = 3
NP_VERSION = 'MT19937'

def npstate_to_pystate(npstate):
    """
    Convert state of a NumPy RandomState object to a state
    that can be used by Python's Random.
    """
    version, keys, pos, has_gauss, cached_gaussian = npstate
    pystate = (
        PY_VERSION,
        tuple(map(int, keys)) + (int(pos),),
        cached_gaussian if has_gauss else None,
    )
    return pystate


def pystate_to_npstate(pystate):
    """
    Convert state of a Python Random object to state usable
    by NumPy RandomState.
    """
    version, (*keys, pos), cached_gaussian = pystate
    has_gauss = cached_gaussian is not None
    npstate = (
        NP_VERSION,
        keys,
        pos,
        has_gauss,
        cached_gaussian if has_gauss else 0.0
    )
    return npstate
```

Comment: Thank you for your very informative response. I learned everything that I wanted to and more.